# Know which month was 6 months ago, Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query to get the daily salary average for the last six months but I want to select the month too...
For instance if current month is August then six months ago was March.

this is the query I have:

```
SELECT 
/*Month here*/
(round((sum(TotalReceived)/6)/26)) as 'Daily Salary Average'
FROM SalaryPaymentReceipt 
WHERE PaymentDate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH AND CURDATE()
AND FK_Employee=12345;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the BETWEEN definition, there is a left and a right hand side. Which side would you use as a SELECT field to get the desired result?

Comment: Are you looking for exactly 6 months from today or do you want to include the whole month 6 months ago?

They are different requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself

this is it

```
SELECT 
Month(subdate(curdate(),interval 6 month)) as 'Month', 
(round((sum(TotalReceived)/6)/26)) as 'Daily Salary Average'
FROM SalaryPaymentReceipt 
WHERE PaymentDate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH AND CURDATE()
AND FK_Employee=12345;
```